# Dependency does not support null safety,version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

Here is the pubspec.yaml file code given below .https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnjgz.png. Here is the pic of the terminal after running flutter pub get

```
 name: hydrabadi_rishte
    description: A new Flutter project.     


 publish_to: "none" 
    #version: 1.0.1+2
    version: 1.0.2+3
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.18.6 <3.0.0"
      flutter: ">=2.12.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  dropdown_button2:
  timer_button: ^2.0.0
  dropdownfield: ^1.0.3
  custom_radio_grouped_button: any
  checkbox_grouped: ^1.8.0
  dropdown_plus:
  http:
  pin_entry_text_field: 0.1.4
  pinput: ^2.2.8
  timer_count_down:
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  flutter_search_bar: ^1.0.3
  quds_popup_menu: 0.0.1+1
  like_button: ^2.0.4
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.1
  dropdown_search:
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  sizer: ^2.0.15
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.2.0
  file_picker: ^3.0.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  image_cropper: ^3.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  flutter_animate: ^3.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.5
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.6
  mailer: ^5.0.0
  video_player: ^2.3.8
  chewie: ^1.0.2
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0

  get:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11     

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter    
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0    
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true    
  assets:
    - assets/
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnjgz.png
Here is the pic of the terminal after running flutter pub get.So I tried using --no-sound-null-safety and flutter run -d chrome --no-sound-null-safety but nothing worked so give me a efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dependency that has not been migrated. The pin_entry_text_field probably got discontinued and is no longer compatible.

Maybe switch to https://pub.dev/packages/pintextfield

Which is also a package for pin entry and supports null-safety.